# Problems understanding context and contextwrapper

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, android-context

I'm not able to understand these classes. I've been trying to create a new file in a new directory on my internal storage, put some text in it and then to read it out. This does not seem to work without the ContextWrapper. So I tried this:

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
  ...
 class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

 ....
 private void searchAndSave(String s) throws IOException {
....
   ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
   File folder = cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   File fileInFolder = new File(folder, "fileInFolder");

   String string = "Hello world!";
   FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("fileInFolder",
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
   outputStream.close();

   File fl = new File(cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+"/fileInFolder");
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new   InputStreamReader(fin));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line).append("\n");
   }
   String result = sb.toString();
   reader.close();
   fin.close();
   }
}
```

Creating the file does not work without the ContextWrapper. I've been reading a lot, but I still have problems to understand, what the Context and the Contextwrapper actually do and why I need them to create a file. Additionally in my code the creating of the FileInputStream does not work. When the program reaches

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
```

I always get the error:

```
05-21 11:18:25.721: W/System.err(7344): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/data/data/com.example.dice/app_folder/fileInFolder: open failed: 
ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I really would appreciate some help with understanding and solving this problem.

UPDATE: I made a more spare Activity, maybe now it's easier to reconstruct the whole thing. (Should I have done this in a new answer, or is it okay to edit my first posting?) Even though I don't get an error message when trying to create a file, is doesn't seem to work. Here I try reading the "Hello world" string, but I get a FileNotFoundException (EISDIR). Just for you to know :)

```
public class FolderActivity extends Activity {
public final static String TAG = "FolderActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_folder);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_folder);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                folder();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
    private void folder() throws IOException{
        Log.d(TAG, "folder");
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
        Log.d(TAG, "cw = new ContextWrapper");
        File folder = cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "folder = cw.getDir");
        File fileInFolder = new File(folder, "fileInFolder");
        Log.d(TAG, "fileInFolder = new File");
        /*Log.d(TAG,
                "fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath()"
                        + fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath());*/

        String string = "Hello world!";
// Aksioms suggestion
        if (!fileInFolder.exists() && !fileInFolder.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("file", "Couldn't create file " + fileInFolder);
        } else { Log.d(TAG, "file created"); }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("fileInFolder",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Log.d(TAG,
                "fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath()"
                        + fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        String s = fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            getStringFromFile(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    //Make sure you close all streams.
    fin.close();        
    return ret;
}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: What was the problem without the wrapper?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly it is doing. My main problem is, that I don't get the program to read out a file. I want to know and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a file which does not exists. 
Make sure that you check and create the file if it does not exsist:

```
if (!fl.exists() && !fl.mkdirs()) { 
                Log.e("file", "Couldn't create file " + fl);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Yes the getDir creats the folder if it is not created.

```
File folder = cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But the problem is here

```
 File fileInFolder = new File(folder, "fileInFolder");
   String string = "Hello world!";
   FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("fileInFolder",
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In here you try to open a file that does not exsist, you just constructed a new file named fileInFolder, but you actually do not have that folder yet.

Try to use the code that I wrote at the first place, before the openFileOutput("fileInFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); :

```
if (!fileInFolder.exists() && !fileInFolder.mkdirs()) { 
                    Log.e("file", "Couldn't create file " + fileInFolder);
    }
```

Try this and tell me how it goes.

**EDIT 2:**

OK I found the problem it was so obvious. The mistake was that we created the fileInFolder as a directory, and you can not write anything there :D

What we should have done is this:

Remove my code for creating the fileInFolder.

```
if (!fileInFolder .exists() && !fileInFolder .mkdirs()) {
    Log.e("file", "Couldn't create file " + fileInFolder );
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "file created");
}
```

we do not need to create it because we will use it as a file. So the change I have made in your code is this:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileInFolder);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    out.write(string);
    out.close();
```

Add this between the line String string = "Hello world!"; and the first Log.d... This is the correct way to write in a file.

**The whole code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String TAG = "FolderActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_folder);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                folder();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void folder() throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "folder");
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "cw = new ContextWrapper");
    File folder = cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d(TAG, "folder = cw.getDir");
    File fileInFolder = new File(folder, "fileInFolder");
    Log.d(TAG, "fileInFolder = new File");
    /*
     * Log.d(TAG, "fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath()" +
     * fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath());
     */

    String string = "Hello world!";

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileInFolder);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    out.write(string);
    out.close();
    Log.d(TAG,
            "fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath()"
                    + fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    String s = fileInFolder.getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        getStringFromFile(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getStringFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    // Make sure you close all streams.
    fin.close();
    return ret;
}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

Check if you have this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: I thought File folder = cw.getDir("folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); would create the folder, if it doesn't exist. And why can something be written into the file then?

Comment: OK I think I made a mistake .. look at my edit. I think the problem was there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can try in a few hours and then will tell you :)

Comment: No problem. We will make this work in any case. After that it will be more easy to understand the code. :)

Comment: I did what you said and put your if assignment direct before the `openFileOutput`. I don't get the Log.e message. I put  `else { Log.d(TAG, "file created"); }` behind your if, and this is the message I get now.

Comment: I made an update with a new activity to my question.

Comment: I'll take a look and tell you. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I've edited my code but still get an EISDIR error. It would be very nice, if you could post your code. Maybe I messed up something.

Comment: Things got clearer with your code. I thank you again :)